# Get ENTRY key press on textbox from getElementsByClassName

Tags: javascript

There I have a textbox and select element.

I would like to trigger an alert if anyone entered an entry key in the textbox. I wrote JS code to get textbox, but unable to perform trigger operation. How could I do it?

```js
var tab = document.getElementsByClassName('PDSCriteriaSections')[0];
var children = tab.childNodes[0].childNodes[0];
var textbox = children.firstChild.innerHTML;
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td class="PDSCriteriaSections">
      <div>
        <ul>
          <li>
            <input type="text">
            <select>
              <option value="MTJobNo">Job No</option>
              <option value="EmptyInDate">EmptyIn Date</option>
              <option value="ContainerNo">Container No</option>
            </select>
            <input value="-" style="display: none;" type="button">
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/ctpn6mr6/

Comment: Give the input an `id` and access it using `document.getElementById` instead of all those chains of `.childNodes`s.

Comment: Explain more. What do exactly want?

Comment: @ibrahimmahrir I dont have access to change the html code. My requirement is to trigger an event when enter key is pressed in the textbox.

Answer (score 0):

```
// ...
// textbox redefintion
var textbox = children.firstChild;
textbox.addEventListener("keydown", function(e){
    // 13 is the keyCode of enter button
    if(e.keyCode == 13){
        alert("Enter was pressed");
    }
});
```

Comment: If this textbox was inside a form, you'd better add `e.preventDefault()` inside the `if` body so the form won't get submitted.